# Does React Router v4 support React 16 (Fiber)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to migrate my app from React 15.6 to React 16.
For now using React Router v2.8.1 and can`t compile build, because have an error with PropTypes.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined.
```

I know in React 16 PropTypes has moved in separate package.

Does React Router v4  already support React 16 (Fiber)?
Should I update it?

Comment: when I install react 16 with react-router v4, npm gives me warning that react-router requires react 15, so I guess not

Answer (score 3):

Yes It should, from new release of [`react-router v4.1.2`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md), They have fixed most of the warning errors and with [`React 16 beta`](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10294). It should work if you've resolved all the warning messages from 15.x.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it supports it. I use react 16 and react-router 4 in my project.